# What are the steps to instantiate the chrome browser in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want the detailed steps. Like from scratch and in serial order.
I know that we want to install the `chromeDriver` then:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: yes i have a query like steps that will lead to instantiate the chrome browser:

Comment: How can i instanciate only one time and use in many tests steps (i'm using test ng when i instanciate it i got many chrome window for each test ! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Indrajit
that all for it any way refer the following

Step1: [Click Here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to download chromedriver.exe

Step2: add the following code to your java file

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/your/path/to/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Beside this if you are looking for any other query, please be specific on it.

Answer (score 0):

The two code lines you mentioned, are the basic steps are required to instantiate the chrome driver. If you have any specific query then you should mention that.